# Possible to Compress Request in Netty?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

Is it possible to compress requests in Netty? I understand [HttpContentCompressor](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpContentCompressor.html) exists but it only seems to compress responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. 
You have to add handler in your pipeline.

Your pipeline must look something like this .

```
// Create a default pipeline implementation.
ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();

// Decodes ChannelBuffer into HTTP Request message
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());

// Encodes HTTTPRequest message to ChannelBuffer
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());

// Compress
pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor(1));

// Handler to dispatch processing to our services
pipeline.addLast("handler", new YourHttpRequestHandler());
```